# Openshift route rejected

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm, argocd

We have configured ArgoCD to deploy multiple helm chart of our infrastructure.

We have an helm chart that depends on another, but they are deployed using 2 different applications in ArgoCD

1. The helm chart A, deployed by the ArgoCd application A, creates all the pods and services for a vendor application
2. The helm chart B, deployed by the ArgoCD application B, create additional resources in the same namespace: e.g external secrets, cronjobs, and Routes...

The 2 helm charts are deployed by different ArgoCD application especially because they have different life cycles and deployments workflows.

So far so good, then we tested our disaster recovery procedure deploying everything from scratch.
Since the routes created by the Application A need the Services created by the Application B, we have the following race condition:

- If the routes of the Application A are created before that the Application B creates the services, the routes will be in a rejected status forever

If we delete the routes, ArgoCD will recreate them and then they will be accepted since the services will be already present.

Now the question is: How can we configure ArgoCD or Openshift to constantly retry to recreate the routes if they have been rejected till they are accepted?

Thank you